# Get two tables from same table SQL

Tags: sql, database, join, select

I have two tables

**Cities**:

```
id  name
------------
1   Helsinki
2   Tukholma
3   Oslo
4   Turku
```

**Flights**

```
id  where_id    to_id
---------------------
1   1           2
2   1           3
3   2           3
4   2           4
```

I want to get this result

```
Helsinki    Tukholma
Helsinki    Oslo
Tukholma    Oslo
Tukholma    Turku
```

How do I compose the query? Result has two name columns and I can't get around it?

Comment: JOIN cities twice.  BTW, wouldn't from_id be a better column name than where_id?

Comment: From would be better. I was thinking whereto and split it... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join twice:

```
select c1.name where_city, c2.name to_city
from flights f
inner join cities c1 on c1.id = f.where_id
inner join cities c2 on c2.id = f.to_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two joins:

```
select f.*, cw.name, ct.name
from flights f join
     cities cw
     on f.where_id = cw.id join
     cities ct
     on f.to_id = ct.id;
```

Comment: f.*, needs to be removed. Thanks.

Comment: @Lasse . . . So remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Pretty clear. No JOINs

```
SELECT A.name, B.name FROM cities A, cities B, flights F WHERE F.where_id=A.id AND L.to_id=B.id;
```